# Java write data to a file and download it?

Tags: java, desktop-application, filechooser

I am new bi to Java, facing an issue with desktop application. I have to write data and output it as "data.txt"(means without writing file to a fixed location) and let the user download this file. I had searched a lot over internet but didn't get any proper solution. All suggestions are welcome.

Note : I am using NetBeans IDE 7.0.1

Comment: "downloading" ==> are you writing a web application or a desktop application? For the latter case, a "save file" dialog would be appropriate.

Comment: Thanks for quick response @Matten. I'm writing Desktop Application and i have to write the contents in a file at run time(not at any phisical location) and then have to show a save(download) dialog box.

Comment: see this link http://www.coderanch.com/t/579127/Streams/java/Saving-Text-file-at-runtime

Comment: @dirtyhandsphp: Are you trying to say that you build a Simple Notepad but has download feature?

Comment: @Zaz As per your example I have to mention the file path where i just waana save the file. But in my case user would save the file on his/her desired location at run time as we do when we download any file from internet.

Comment: @Crazenezz : Didn't get you properly but i think yes.

Comment: I got a link http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-download-file-from-website-java-jsp/

3rd example meet my requirements. But don't know how to use HttpServletResponse response to work for me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Save the data in a stream and then display a FileChooser dialog to let the user decide where to save the file to. Then write the stream to the selected file.

More on file choosers can be read here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html

Comment: As per your answer i think i have to use the browse button and ask the user to enter file location as the link suggests and the content would be written at that particular file. But that would be great if i could give user an option to download a file. Or is it possible only in case of web applications?

Comment: You could have downoading etc from web server from your desktop app this is not a problem you just need to think about it in steps. First ask server for what files it can serve (are ready to download) you could present it to the user the way you like then when user selects you would do as guys suggest use a file chooser to show where and into which file to store it.

Comment: there is no "download" in a desktop application, as the file contents reside on the client machine already. So the file chooser does the same as the download dialog on a web site, without sending data through your network connection.

Comment: @Boro and Matten : Thanks to both of you. Matten i'm accepting your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Once you create your file on server you can then do a similar thing I did for sending image files to my clients (in my case it is a `JSP` but it really doesn't matter where your client is):

```
/**
 * Writes file with a given path to the response.
 * @param pathToFile
 * @param response
 * @throws IOException if there was some problem writing the file.
 */
public static void writeFile(String pathToFile, ServletResponse response) throws IOException {
    try(InputStream is = new FileInputStream(pathToFile);
        OutputStream out = new Base64OutputStream(response.getOutputStream());){
        IOUtils.copy(is, out);
    }
}
```

Those are the imports it uses:

[import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64OutputStream;](http://commons.apache.org/codec/)

[import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;](http://commons.apache.org/io/)

On the client (in your desktop app) you would use the same [IOUtils](http://commons.apache.org/io/) to decode it from [Base64](http://commons.apache.org/codec/) and then you can store it wherever you want. 
For this bit actually @Matten gives a neat solution (+1).

Answer (score 0):

I have example with `JFileChooser` but sorry still didn't get your point about the download thing.

```
BufferedOutputStream buff = null;
BufferedReader reader = null;
JFileChooser fileChooser;
File file;

fileChooser.showSaveDialog(this);

file = new File(fileChooser.getSelectedFile().toString());
file.createNewFile();

reader = new BufferedReader(new StringReader("String text"));
buff = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file));

String str;
while ((str = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    buff.write(str.getBytes());
    buff.write("\r\n".getBytes());
}
```

Comment: I just wanna a dialog box same as which at the first moment appear when you try to download anything over internet.